# #define for ARM microcontrollers

Tags: c, arm

What does string

```
#define RCC                 ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)
```

mean?

I understand that that is a pointer's definition and RCC_BASE stands for  uint_32 0x400021000 according to following lines

```
#define RCC_BASE              (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x00001000)
#define AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00020000)
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
```

But why does the definition have two types: RCC_TypeDef * and uint_32?

Comment: Because each macro has it's own meaning, and must be correct when used independently.

Comment: If you give more context (e.g. typedef) somebody could show you how to use that macro.

Comment: It is basic C language stuff, they are using the struct to create offsets 0x00, 0x04, etc (with names RCC->something) to the 0x40021000 base.  Has nothing to do with ARM nor the ARM portion of this chip.  the uint32_t in PERIPH_BASE wasnt necessary, maybe they were getting a compiler warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define RCC                 ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)
```

means macro which is of type `RCC_TypeDef *` and *points* to address `RCC_BASE` in MCU address space.

`RCC_BASE` is address where RCC registers are in MCU address space.

Address itself is number therefore it has `(uint32_t)` infront.

This type of macro allows you to use registers with pointer access

```
//Read RCC register APB1ENR
uint32_t apb1enr_Reg = RCC->APB1ENR;
```

Comment: Can I defined it as follows 
uint_32 RCC_BASE = 0x400021000;
RCC_TypeDef *RCC = NULL;
RCC = RCC_BASE;
?

Comment: Since `#define RCC...` exists, you will get error if you do your code. You can do this: `RCC_TypeDef* myRcc; myRcc = (RCC_TypeDef *)RCC_BASE;`, but I don't know why would you do that. Use CMSIS declarations.

Comment: I was just trying to understand it better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
#define RCC                 ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)
```

is simply explicitly casting the address pointed to by `RCC_BASE` to a pointer to whatever the `typedef` that `RCC_TYPEDEF` defines elsewhere.

For example, if `RCC_TYPEDEF` is defined to be `long`, then `RCC` will be defined to be:

```
#define RCC                 ((long *) RCC_BASE)
```